# Как выравнить контейнеры в одну сторку? Html, css

Tags: css, flexbox

Хочу чтобы контейнеры выравнились ровно по красной линии. Какая это команда в css?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```css
/* Стандартный метод */
.elementsParent {
display: flex;
}

/* или */

.elementsParent {
display: inline-flex;
}

/* или */

.elementsParent {
display: ruby; /* Или его под-зачения: ruby-base, ruby-base-container, ruby-text, ruby-container */
}

/* или */

.elementsParent {
display: block ruby;
}
```

Также для настройки позиции flexbox-а советую использовать `flex-direction`:

```css
.elementsParent {
flex-direction: row; /* Альтернативы: row-reverse, column, column-reverse */
}
```